# shadow box overlay click fadeaway

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, shadowbox

I've got this shadow box and what I'm trying to do is make it fade away when I click on the overlay, but right now it works only if I click on the actual image itself. I've tried everything I can in the code but still no dice, the code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('a.shadowbox').click(function(e) {
    $('body').css('overflow-y', 'hidden'); 
    $('<div id="overlay"></div>') 
        .css('top', $(document).scrollTop())
        .css('opacity', '0') 
        .animate({'opacity': '0.9'}, 'slow')
    .appendTo('body');

    $('<div id="shadowbox"></div>')
        .hide()
    .appendTo('body');

    $('<img>')
        .attr('src', $(this).attr('href'))
        .load(function() {
            var top = ($(window).height() - $('#shadowbox').height()) / 2; 
            var left = ($(window).width() - $('#shadowbox').width()) / 2;
            $('#shadowbox') 
            .css({ 
                'top': top + $(document).scrollTop(),
                'left': left
                })
            .fadeIn();
    })
    .click(function() {
        $('#overlay, #shadowbox')
            .fadeOut('slow', function(){ 
                $(this).remove(); 
            $('body').css('overflow-y', 'auto');
            });
        })
    .appendTo('#shadowbox');
    return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: This sort of question really needs a mockup (JSFiddle or SO snippet).

Comment: Because you demonstrated that event handlers *can* be added to a disconnected element +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

The `click` event is currently a part of the chain for `$('img')` (i.e attr, load, click, appendTo).

Instead try adding the click event to the overlay:

```
$('#overlay').click(...)
```

Comment: @Ted right you are about the element id - if I had only read the question correctly... :)